# Inaccurate distance measurements qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to reproject a 1/9 arc second DEM from EPSG:4269 to EPSG: 2264.  I also need to DEM to be in feet so I have been using the raster calculator to multiply the original DEM to feet.  When I assign a new projection to the layer and change the CRS of the project the measurement tool is way off.
[image: FIRST]
before converting to feet and changing CRS
[image: Second]
After.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about QGIS, changing the CRS on a layer is not the same thing as projecting to a new CRS. If you have a layer with X Y defined by latitude and longitude, and then just change the CRS to a projected coordinate system, the X Y values do not change. Basically it takes those latitude and longitude values and interprets them in terms of units of the projected CRS that you changed to, so everything will be completely messed up like you are seeing.

If you just want measurements in EPSG 2264 you can change the CRS of your map by selecting the button in the lower right of the screen. When selecting your CRS check the box at the top that says "Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation (OTF)."

This will keep your layer in 4269 like it should be and transform it to 2264 so that your measurements in the map are in ft.

If you really want to change your layer, I think if you do a save as, and select 2264 as the CRS it will transform your layer and save it with the new CRS.